# I have two huge sequencefiles where i want to extract the same linenumbers from file1 in file2

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, awk

I have my two sequencefiles and I have a list of rows/lines of interest from file1. I want to extract the lines with the same linenumber as in file1. The list is just 1 column of numbers.

I tried using awk in a loop, but all I get is an empty file as output file.

My code looks like this:

```
for i in <listfile>;
do awk -F lnr="$i" 'NR==lnr' <file2> > outputfile
```

The output file is created but is just empty.

I could not find this question being asked before, but if so sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Tried the `join` command or the `comm` command?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: generally speaking you want to limit the number of times you have to scan your input file; a typical (`awk`) solution is to load the first file (`file1`) into an `awk` array and then use said array when processing the 2nd file (`file2`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question - file 1 has a list of "line numbers" and you desire to print those lines in file2:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{line[$1]=1;next}{if(line[FNR]==1)print FNR, $0}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. i wanted to keep it as short as possible. My file1 are dna-sequences where are just some lines of interest. I can extract them using a unique identifier but these identifiers are missing in file2.  But the sequences of interest in file1 and file2 are in the same line, so i extracted the line numbers of file1, which i called "list of line numbers".

Comment: Oh and it works as I wanted it to. Thank you very much! You just made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the input...

```
for i in {a..z}; do echo $i; done > /tmp/list-1
for i in {z..a}; do echo $i; done > /tmp/list-2
```

The current line of each file will be stored in FNR, so you can use that.

```
$ awk -v a=4 -v b=9 'FNR >= a && FNR <= b { print FILENAME, NR, FNR, $0 }'  /tmp/list-*
```

Sample output:

```
/tmp/list-1 4 4 d
/tmp/list-1 5 5 e
/tmp/list-1 6 6 f
/tmp/list-1 7 7 g
/tmp/list-1 8 8 h
/tmp/list-1 9 9 i
/tmp/list-2 30 4 w
/tmp/list-2 31 5 v
/tmp/list-2 32 6 u
/tmp/list-2 33 7 t
/tmp/list-2 34 8 s
/tmp/list-2 35 9 r
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and time